# Understanding C++ template class

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I was given a C++ assignment and I'm trying to understand the material before the actual coding process. I'm requested to simulate a "store" that can sell products, receive orders, manage inventory etc. I also need to implement a database to log every sale. **I have to implement** it with a Template class that will actually be dynamic array. The actual strategy that **I have to achieve** is two arrays(one twice the size of the other) and when the smaller one is full - the bigger is half-full, so i delete the smaller and create a new one - twice as big of the other array and so on.

My questions:
Is there a real reason for Template here? or is it just for practicing? I can't see where would I be using the Template as a generic form?

Maybe someone knows of a good relevant link with explanation and/or example.

Comment: There could be a reason: create a `Store` of particular products. `Store<Food>` or `Store<Toys>`. The latter won't be able to sell meat, for example. (I wish it did).

Comment: If I understand your task correctly, you are basically instructed to write your own implementation of `std::vector`? If so, then templates serve the purpose of generalization of what items your array can hold.

Comment: Please tag assignments "homework" (not "class"...I've fixed this for you), and... yknow, it does help if you give the relevant section from an assignment verbatim.  Or at least excerpt what you've been told.  **However** you should then in detail describe your specific confusion as a reasoned argument about the literal assignment.  (It's a bit easier to process this than the [telephone game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers).)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to store an array of products, orders etc. In that case you can use your generic array class and create different instantiation of the template like `Array<Product>` and `Array<Order>`. In this way you can reuse the array code instead of writing different array class for each one of them.